# Horizontal scroll and cut div

Tags: css

I have a top bar to put in my blog :

```
<nav class="top-bar blog">
    STACKOVERFLOWSTACKOVERFLOWSTACKOVERFLOWSTACKOVERFLOWSTACKOVERFLOWSTACKOVERFLOWSTACKOVERFLOWSTACKOVERFLOWSTACKOVERFLOWSTACKOVERFLOWSTACKOVERFLOW
</nav>

<style type="text/css">
    .top-bar.blog {
        width: 100%;
        white-space: no-wrap;
        background: violet;
        ...
    }
    body {
        background: black;
    }
</style>
```

When I resize my browser window to a small size to see the horizontal bar I get this:

[image]

Which is the expected result.

When I scroll horizontally to the right here is the result:

[image]

The div is cut.

Strangely, there is the same problem on stackoverflow.com's top-bar.

How can I prevent this so the size can stay adjusted to the right part of the windows instead of being "cut"?

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried the css declaration `width: auto; overflow-x: visible;` ?

Comment: Please refer to my comment : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070415/horizontal-scroll-and-cuted-div/18070461?noredirect=1#comment26445025_18070461

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMnEF/1/) works for me.

Set `overflow:hidden` `width:100%` and then just some paddding and margin.

Comment: The content can only be seen by totally stretching the windows to the right. That is not what I want, I have a static content, that should be shown as it is a top-bar.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I understand. Also, this view should be static. It's just that JSFiddle just has 4 different views so it looks weird. What is it you want to do, do you just want topbar that doesn't have weird scrolly issues? If that's the case, try taking out ALL of your CSS and starting with just width, margin, padding, and background. Then start adding attributes 1 by 1 until you find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the top bar to move at all, you could try `position: fixed`, remove the width and set top, left and right positions. E.g.:

```
.top-bar.blog {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    height: 50px;
    white-space: no-wrap;
    background: violet;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Change the top, left, right, and height numbers to whatever you want.